# Java - Is Spring's ReactorNettyWebSocketClient thread safe?

Tags: java, spring, websocket, netty, reactor

I'm wondering what best-practice usage is of Spring's WebSocketClient implementation, ReactorNettyWebSocketClient. I can't find details of this anywhere in the documentation.

Can I use this client as a singleton for all my web socket connections to different URLs? I have upwards of ten servers I need to connect to. Or should I instantiate a new instance per connection?

For example, is this acceptable usage?

```
@Bean
public WebSocketClient webSocketClient() {
    return new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ReactorNettyWebSocketClient`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webflux/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/socket/client/ReactorNettyWebSocketClient.java) is stateless except `HttpClient` field.
[`HttpClient`](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/blob/master/src/main/java/reactor/netty/http/client/HttpClient.java) is 100% stateless, so it is safe to have singleton